# Access Subquery On mulitple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

This SQL query needs to be done in ACCESS.

I am trying to do a subquery on the total sales, but I want to link the sale to the province AND to product. The below query will work with one or the other: (po.product_name = allp.all_products) AND (p.province = allp.all_province); -- but it will no take both.

I will be including every month into this query, once I can figure out the subquery on with two criteria.

```
Select

p.province as [Province],
po.product_name as [Product],
all_price


FROM
(purchase_order po
INNER JOIN person p
on p.person_id = po.person_id)

left join
(
select
po1.product_name AS [all_products],
sum(pp1.price) AS [all_price],
p1.province AS [all_province]
from (purchase_order po1
INNER JOIN product pp1
on po1.product_name = pp1.product_name)
INNER JOIN person p1
on po1.person_id = p1.person_id
group by po1.product_name, pp1.price, p1.province
)
as allp
on  (po.product_name = allp.all_products) AND (p.province = allp.all_province);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first select sql into a table by giving it an alias and join table 1 to table 2.  I don't have your table structure or data to test it but I think this will lead you down the right path:

```
select table1.*, table2.*
from
(Select
p.province as [Province],
po.product_name as [Product]
--removed this  ,all_price 
FROM
(purchase_order po
INNER JOIN person p
on p.person_id = po.person_id) table1

left join
(
select
po1.product_name AS [all_products],
sum(pp1.price) AS [all_price],
p1.province AS [all_province]
from (purchase_order po1
INNER JOIN product pp1
on po1.product_name = pp1.product_name)
INNER JOIN person p1
on po1.person_id = p1.person_id
group by po1.product_name, pp1.price, p1.province --check your group by, I dont think you want pp1.price here if you want to aggregate
) as table2  --changed from allp
on  (table1.product = table2.all_products) AND (table1.province = table2.all_province);
```